# perl substitute numbers to alphabet,used with for

Tags: perl, substitution

Perl substitute all Numbers to Alphabet

```
abc4xyz5u
```

to

```
abcdxyzeu
```

I try this,but it not work:

```
echo 'abc4xyz5u' | perl -pe'@n=1..9;@a=a..j;@h{@n}=@a;s#$n[$_]#$h{$&}#g for 0..$#n'
```

I know y/[1-9]/[a-j]/, but I want to use a substitute.

Comment: Re "*I know y/[1-9]/[a-j]/*", The correct usage is `y/1-9/a-i/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is within

```
s#$n[$_]#$h{$&}#g for 0..$#n
```

You expect `$_` to be your input (so that `s###` is applied on it), but also `$n[$_]` to use the `$_` from the for loop (`0` to `$#n`). If you were to add a print, you'd notice that `$_`'s value within this loop is `0` to `$#n`, rather than your input.

What you could do instead to fix it is something like:

```
$r=$_; $r=~s#$n[$_]#$h{$&}#g for 0..$#n; $_=$r
```

But that's much more complicated that it has to be. I would instead do:

```
s#([1-9])#$h{$1}#g
```

Or, without using `%h` (since, let's face it, an hash with `0 => a`, `1 => b` etc. should be an array):

```
perl -pe '@a="a".."j"; s#([1-9])#$a[$1-1]#g'
```

Or, without requiring an array at all (I'll let you decide if you find it easier or harder to read; personally I'm fine with it),

```
perl -pe 's/([1-9])/chr(ord("a")+$1-1)/ge'
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation."s#$n[$_]#$h{$&}#g for 0..$#n" I think I get it now.

Comment: Nitpicks: (1) The `\d` matches some 300+ Unicode "digits" along with `[0-9]` ... things like `٤` for example (`perl -CS -wE'$v="\N{U+0664}"; $v =~ /(\d)/; say $1'`) etc.  Why not just `[0-9]`? (2) The `$&` is fine since v5.20 (and I'm still not sure that it has good performance), and capture+`$1` is far more readily recognized and understood

Comment: Re "*Why not just `[0-9]`*", More like `[1-9]`, based on the OP's snippets.

Comment: @zdim I have mixed feelings regarding `\d`: yes it matches more than just `[0-9]`, but how often is that really an issue? Weird unicode digits don't just pop in strings everywhere for no reason. That being said, `[1-9]` matches more closely what OP wanted, so I've changed for that. Regarding `$&`: I'm personally used to it, and so is OP. But the point of SO being provide answers that has useful in the future, I've changed it to `$1` as it might easier for less experienced users (and regarding performances: I think we both agree that in this case it doesn't matter!) Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to write it properly as a perl script.
The one liner you mentioned is little hard to understand.

```
use strict;                                                            
use warnings;

my @alphabets = ("a".."z");

my $input = $ARGV[0];

$input =~ s/(\d)/$alphabets[$1 - 1]/g;

print $input;
```

Run -

> perl substitute.pl abc4xyz5u

Output -

> abcdxyzeu

I am serching for the number in the string and replacing it with the alphabet on the same position(remenber array start form 0 index and hence 'position -1') in the 'alphabets' array

Comment: OK,Thanks a lot! How to use substitute with for loop?

Comment: @Steven if you want the same behavior as your one-line, you should do something like `while(my $input = <>) { $input =~ s/(\d)/$alphabets[$1 - 1]/g; print $input; }` (`-p` flag basically wraps your code in `while(<>) { ... } continue { print }` (more or less))